# Hiding mouse cursor with glfw

Tags: c++, x11, glfw

I'm working with a game made with glfW and running in Ubuntu. My problem is that hiding the mouse cursor with the line

```
glfwDisable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR);
```

causes some machines to simply disregard the mouse input, and thus breaks the game.

Has anyone faced this problem? If so, what was your workaround?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since glfw 3.0 the API call has changed, you must use `glfwSetInputMode` with a pointer of your window.

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);
```

For more information see http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html

Answer (score 19):

It sounds like you may want to use `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED` (GLFW 3+).

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

`GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED` **hides and locks** the cursor so it can't leave your window, just like `glfwDisable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR);`.

Source: [GLFW Input Guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.1/input.html#input_cursor_mode)